# How to export a value from <select> option in an external component?

Tags: javascript

I have a component called plan.js, and in that component I have the dropdown. What I am trying to do is get the value and import it in another component. What I tried so far was the onChange in the select, and wrote a few functions but nothing from other pages here on the website seemed to work.

```
<select>
   <option value="value1">€2.95/month</option>
   <option value="value2">€29.95/year</option>
</select>
```

I want to put the value in the checkout.js component as such:

```
const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
      mode: "subscription",
      lineItems: [{ price: "{value}", quantity: 1 }],
```

If I hardcore the price: "value" it works and gets me to checkout, but i want when a user selects from the dropdown, to get the value of the option and send it to the checkout. Preferably, no `id` or `this.` because I tried almost all viable methods i found and gave me undefined errors. I think the solution has something to do with exporting a `const` with the value, which might need to be inside a function to `handleChange` and in `select` to `onChange={handleChange()}` but if I have no clue. I'm using gatsby js, if that matters. Obviously, I`m a noob with almost no experience so please, help.

Comment: `lineItems: [{ price: document.getElementById('your selector to select element').value, quantity: 1 }]` This might work for you

Comment: I don't know how to thank you, you are THE BEST!!!

Comment: @AdarshMohan Please put that suggestion in an answer, and peterk94d, please accept it. This will help others with similar problems find your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
const { error } = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
  mode: "subscription",
  lineItems: [
    {
      price: document.getElementById('your selector to select element').value,
      quantity: 1
    }
  ],
  /* .. */
})
```

You will need to use the [element selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to get the value from the select field and use that value instead of `{value}`.